# Java: Not operator in if statement prints "error" and correct statement?

Tags: java, printing, logical-operators

This is driving me bonkers. This is a very simple program. It prints only "error" when operation is wrong, so that's good. But the problem I have is when the correct answer is fed into the console it prints both the correct statement and error. I don't understand why. I am sure it's very easy but I am not seeing it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MeowSample{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner okay = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a letter ");
    char letter = okay.next().charAt(0);
    if(letter != 'x' || letter != 'y' || letter != 'z' || letter != 'q'){
        System.out.println("Errorrr");
    }
    if(letter == 'x' || letter == 'y' || letter == 'z'|| letter == 'q'){
        System.out.println("Correct!");
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Look at the logic in your conditionals. If `letter` ='s `y`, then `letter` does not equal `x`.

Comment: Any letter would satisfy a condition `letter != 'x' || letter != 'y'`, wouldn't it?

Comment: Ya basically that is the same as saying 'letter != null'

Comment: A good refresher on boolean logic is here: http://codingbat.com/doc/java-if-boolean-logic.html

Comment: I agree quite the derpy move there. I am new to programming if you cannot already tell. Yeah I don't know why but just learning the != sort of confused me a little at first. I see now the && was what I wanted. The NOT operator would just leave all the other options available like if someone chose y, well that's still NOT z therefore error.... If someone chose z well that's still not q and so on...I see my mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your two `if` statements are not mutually exclusive.  Try:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MeowSample{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner okay = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a letter ");
    char letter = okay.next().charAt(0);
    //if(letter != 'x' || letter != 'y' || letter != 'z' || letter != 'q'){
    //    System.out.println("Errorrr");
    //}
    if(letter == 'x' || letter == 'y' || letter == 'z'|| letter == 'q'){ // this one is OK
        System.out.println("Correct!");
    } else { // <-- add the else
        System.out.println("Errorrr");  // Move the error print down here.
    }
}
```

Your original code prints "Error" if `letter` is anything at all - not an x, not a y, not a z, or not a q.  Your original code then prints "Correct" if `letter` is x, y, z, or q.

The revised code first checks for the specific letters you want, then prints error in an `else` block if `letter` isn't one you wanted.

Comment: that won't solve the issue. Instead this will simply always print "Error". The mistake is within the logic of the conditionns

Comment: @Paul fixed - hit Post too soon :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this condition:

```
if(letter != 'x' || letter != 'y' || letter != 'z' || letter != 'q')
```

If `letter` is not 'x' or not 'y' will **always** be true, simply because `letter` can't be both 'x' and 'y'. A bit of boolean algebra shows that:

```
l != 'x' || l != 'y' || ...
--> bracket NOT
!(l == 'x') || !(l == 'y') || ...
--> apply rule "!A || !B is equivalent to !(A && B)" (De Morgan 2)
!((l == 'x') && (l == 'y') && ...)
```

It's obvious that `((l == 'x') && (l == 'y') && ...)` will always evaluate to `false`, unless `'x' == 'y'` is given - it isn't. Apply the NOT-operator, and the final result of the complete condition will always be `true`.

The correct logic operator would be `&&` here:

```
if(letter != 'x' && letter != 'y' && ...
```

would only evaluate to true, if `letter` is neither 'x', nor 'y', nor ... . So far for how to fix the problem itself. But in general an approach using mutual exclusive conditions would be more elegant anyways:

```
if(letter == 'x' || letter == 'y' || letter == 'z'|| letter == 'q'){
    System.out.println("Correct!");
}else{
    System.out.println("Errorrr");
}
```